# nats-sub not found after nats-box fresh install

Tags: kubernetes, nats.io

I'm trying to setup a basic NATS service on my kubernetes cluster, according to their documentation, [here](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/nats-kubernetes). I executed the following code:

```
$ helm install test-nats nats/nats

NAME: test-nats
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Jul 14 13:18:09 2022
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
You can find more information about running NATS on Kubernetes
in the NATS documentation website:

  https://docs.nats.io/nats-on-kubernetes/nats-kubernetes

NATS Box has been deployed into your cluster, you can
now use the NATS tools within the container as follows:

  kubectl exec -n default -it deployment/test-nats-box -- /bin/sh -l

  nats-box:~# nats-sub test &
  nats-box:~# nats-pub test hi
  nats-box:~# nc test-nats 4222

Thanks for using NATS!

$ kubectl exec -n default -it deployment/test-nats-box -- /bin/sh -l
             _             _               
 _ __   __ _| |_ ___      | |__   _____  __
| '_ \ / _` | __/ __|_____| '_ \ / _ \ \/ /
| | | | (_| | |_\__ \_____| |_) | (_) >  < 
|_| |_|\__,_|\__|___/     |_.__/ \___/_/\_\
                                           
nats-box v0.11.0
test-nats-box-84c48d46f-j7jvt:~#
```

Now, so far, everything has conformed to their start guide. However, when I try to test the connection, I run into trouble:

```
test-nats-box-84c48d46f-j7jvt:~# nats-sub test &
test-nats-box-84c48d46f-j7jvt:~# /bin/sh: nats-sub: not found
test-nats-box-84c48d46f-j7jvt:~# nats-pub test hi
/bin/sh: nats-pub: not found
```

It looks like the commands weren't found but they should have been installed when I did the `helm install`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have reproduced the set-up on my kubernetes cluster and have successfully deployed the nats box and started a [client subscriber](https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/core-nats/pubsub/pubsub_walkthrough#1.-create-subscriber-1) program in which subscribers listen on subjects, and publishers send messages on specific subjects.

**1. Create Subscriber**

In a shell or command prompt session, start a client subscriber program.

```
 nats sub < subject>
```

Here, < subject > is a subject to listen on. It helps to use unique and well thought-through subject strings because you need to ensure that messages reach the correct subscribers even when wildcards are used.

For example:

```
nats sub msg.test
```

You should see the message: Listening on [msg.test].

**2. Create a Publisher and publish a message**

Create a NATS publisher and send a message.

```
nats pub < subject> < message>
```

Where < subject> is the subject name and < message> is the text to publish.

For example:

```
nats pub msg.test nats-message-1
```

You'll notice that the publisher sends the message and prints: Published [msg.test] : 'NATS MESSAGE'.

The subscriber receives the message and prints: [#1] Received on [msg.test]: 'NATS MESSAGE'.

Here, you have provided the wrong syntax nats-sub and nats-pub which are deprecated. Try using the above commands to give precise results.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. `nats-sub` and `nats-pub` seem to be deprecated and you need to use `nats sub` and `nats pub` instead.